# OData .net Core how to set HTTPS in every link when using SSL Offloading

Tags: c#, ssl, asp.net-core, odata

In my infrastructure I use SSL Offloading so that each request coming from the public Internet, which uses Https, is load balanced and offloaded to Http requests which are sent to the desired internal server.
Using OData for .net Core I need to tell the framework that when new links are generated, for the pagination, streams, metadata and so on, those links must be Https if the incoming request was decorated with the header "X-Forwarded-Proto".

For example when getting data I receive the payload as below:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "http://host/Api/$metadata#Entities",
    "value": [
        ...
    ],
    "@odata.nextLink": "http://host/Api/Entities?$skiptoken=Language-'-',ID-1"
}
```

But I would like this to be:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://host/Api/$metadata#Entities",
    "value": [
        ...
    ],
    "@odata.nextLink": "https://host/Api/Entities?$skiptoken=Language-'-',ID-1"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After going through the OData source code, I can confirm with enough certainty that there isn't any feature which allows to do what I need out of the box.
Nor seems to be possible to override existing classes' behavior.

So the alternative solutions I though about were:

1. Intercept the request using a middleware and replace the schema
2. Intercept the responses and parse the content replacing the metadata links

I decided to go for option 1, below is the solution I adopted.

```
// Middleware used to simulate an https request when behing a load balancer with SSL offloade
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    if (context.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("X-Forwarded-Proto"))
    {
        // The request schema is used by OData to generate all links like, Metadata, Next, GetById and so on
        context.Request.Scheme = "https";
    }
    await next();
});
```

This works for all metadata links, and you can verify it, sending a request with the *Accept Header* with value *'application/json;odata.metadata=full'*.
The second option is error prone and cpu intensive, but my solution might disrupt you requests if used for other purposes.